# Generic class toString manipulation

Tags: java, generics, tostring

I am looking for the most efficient way to print a generic class using only utils. As for now I get a `StackOverflowException`.

```
public class Message<E, B, C> {
    private final int requestNumber;
    private final E data;
    private final B from;
    private final C to;
    private E_MessageStatus status;
    private int replyToRequestNumber;
}
```

this is the `toString()` I am trying to print.

```
public  String toString() {
    return "Message [requestNumber=" +  requestNumber + ", data=" + data+ ", from=" + from+ ", to=" + to
            + ", status=" + status + ", replyToRequestNumber=" + replyToRequestNumber + "]";
}
```

Comment: You probably have a circular reference. Not sure what efficiency has to do with it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel  i am looking  for the most natural way to do it

Comment: This looks perfectly natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto generate generic `toString()` methods in most of the major IDEs (e.g. Eclipse, IntelliJ)

Here is the one generated by IntelliJ:

```
public String toString()
{
        return "Message{" + "requestNumber=" + requestNumber + ", data=" + data + ", from=" + from + ", to=" + to + ", status=" + status + ", replyToRequestNumber=" + replyToRequestNumber + '}';
}
```

Comment: As for the `StackOverflow` exception you need to provide more details about your whole project...

Comment: Or my personal favorite [ReflectionToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) using live templates

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ:
`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` and write "generate toString".

In Eclipse:
Source -> generate toString